# Error installing twisted on windows 10. INCLUDE environment variable is empty

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, twisted, python-3.4

I have installed python 3.4.4 on my windows machine and trying to install twisted library on my machine.

```
>>>python
Python 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 20:20:57) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Here is my output of pip freeze currently

```
>>>pip freeze
constantly==15.1.0
incremental==16.10.1
requests==2.12.4
zope.interface==4.3.3
```

When I am trying to install twisted via pip I am getting this error.

command issued - `pip install twisted`

```
    copying src\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs\thing2.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\twisted\internet\test\fake_CAs
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\twisted\mail\test
    copying src\twisted\mail\test\rfc822.message -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\twisted\mail\test
    copying src\twisted\mail\test\server.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\twisted\mail\test
    copying src\twisted\words\im\instancemessenger.glade -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\twisted\words\im
    copying src\twisted\words\xish\xpathparser.g -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\twisted\words\xish

    running build_ext
    building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
    error: INCLUDE environment variable is empty

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\anurag.sharma\envs\dummy\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ANURAG~1.SHA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-39eej_vn\\twisted\\se
tup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ANURAG~1.SHA\AppData\L
ocal\Temp\pip-zzu50qbz-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\anurag.sharma\envs\dummy\include\site\python3.4\twisted" failed
 with error code 1 in C:\Users\ANURAG~1.SHA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-39eej_vn\twisted\
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work for you.

```
pip install wheel
pip install D:\Documents\Downlaods\Twisted-17.1.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
```

The **27** is corresponding to **python 2.7**

More information here: http://zhangzhenyu.com.cn/blog/install-scrapy-in-python34/

Comment: At least it works when getting the error  "building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"